# Get type from dll with JNA

Tags: java, jna

I am using an external library in my java program. With JNA, I use some methods from the `dll`. However, I want to use a method that returns a custom type defined in the external library. How can I get that specific type from the external library and use it in my program?

Comment: You'll need to either find the sources with the type definitions or reverse engineer them yourself, then create a matching type for it as a Java class with JNA. I would suggest taking a look at JNA's [Getting Started](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md) documentation, and its [examples](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/tree/master/contrib). If you have a specific function ın mind and have access to its source, I would recommend rephrasing your question to "how would I map this function in Java?".

Comment: @cubrr Thank you for the reply! So from what I understand, there is no way to retrieve a class or type from a dll? You can only call methods?

Comment: You can't decompile a native binary and get its typedefs or classes cleanly. That information exists only at compile time. There are tools which can make educated guesses, e.g. IDA Pro and some plugins which can make good guesses based on some artifacts remaining in the compiled data such as ClassInformer, but that's the best you're going to get. You need access to the source **or documentation** to know what types you need to use or what kind of classes to create in Java.

Comment: If you do have access to the source, you can try using [JNAerator](https://github.com/nativelibs4java/JNAerator) to automatically generate Java JNA bindings, but if it doesn't work, you'll need to create them yourself.